# VM ScaleUp Automation Runbook fails

Tags: azure, azure-automation

The VM triggers the alert when the threshold CPU uses exceeded. The alert has 'Action' configured with Automation Runbook. The Runbook runs but it fails without giving any details.

I have choosed Buildin runbook as below.
[image]
In Jobs it shows failed.
[image]

When I look for the 'All Logs', it shows below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use automation runbooks with log alerts. Note that you can use automation runbooks only with 3 alert types i.e., common alerts, activity log alerts and near real-time metric alerts. For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-alert-triggered-runbook#alert-types) document.

If you create an alert rule from Log analytics using "custom log search" signal and put down your percentage cpu custom query then it's considered as log alert. And then if you try to use automation runbook in action section then it fails with exception "The alert data schema - Microsoft.Insights/LogAlert - is not supported".

So I would suggest you to create an alert rule from your VM (or from Azure monitor if you drill down to select your VM resource) using "Percentage CPU" signal (which is a metric alert) and use automation runbook in action section.

I have tested both these scenario's with metric alert and log alert. It does work with metric alert but not with log alert as currently supported alert types are common alerts, activity log alerts and near real-time metric alerts.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: I have created the Alert directly from the VM and it is also showing on the Azure Monitor. I have done in the same way what you have suggested but still no joy.